# Getting variance values for random samples generated from a standard normal distribution using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, gaussian, probability-distribution

I have a function that gives me probability distributions for each class, in terms of a matrix corresponding to mean values and another matrix corresponding to variance values. For example, if I had four classes then I would have the following outputs:

```
y_means = [1,2,3,4]
y_variance = [0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04]
```

I need to do the following calculation to the mean values to continue with the rest of my program:

```
y_means = np.array(y_means)
y_means = np.reshape(y_means,(y_means.size,1))
A = np.random.randn(10,y_means.size)
y_means = np.matmul(A,y_means)
```

Here, I have used the *numpy.random.randn* function to generate random samples from a standard normal distribution, and then multiply this with the matrix with the mean value to obtain a new output matrix. The dimension of the output matrix would then be of the size (10 x 1).

I need to do a similar calculation such that my *output_variances* will also be a (10 x 1) matrix. But it is not meaningful to multiply the variances in the same way with random samples from a standard normal distribution, because this would result in negative values as well. This is undesirable because my ultimate aim would be to create a normal distribution with these mean values and their corresponding variance values using:

```
torch.distributions.normal.Normal(loc=y_means, scale=y_variance)
```

So my question is if there is any method by which I get a variance value for each random sample generated by *numpy.random.randn*? Because then the multplication of such a matrix would make more sense with *output_variance*.

Or if there is any other strategy for this that I might be unaware of, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem mentioned in the question required another matrix of the same dimension as *A* that corresponded to a variance measure for the random samples present in A.

Taking a row-wise or column-wise variance of the matrix denoted by ***A*** using *numpy.var()* didn't give a similar *10 x 4* matrix to multiply with *y_variance*.

I had solved the above problem by using the following approach:

First create a matrix with the same dimensions as A with zero entries, using the following line of code:

```
A_var = np.zeros_like(A)
```

then, using *torch.distributions*, create normal distributions with the values in A as the mean and zeroes as variance:

```
dist_A = torch.distributions.normal.Normal(loc=torch.Tensor(A), scale=torch.Tensor(A_var))
```

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html lists all the operations possible on Normal distributions in PyTorch. The *sample()* method can generate samples from a given distribution for any size. This property was exploited to first generate a sample matrix of size *10 X 10 x 4* and then calculating the variance along axis 0.

```
np.var(np.array(dist2.sample((10,))),axis=0)
```

This would result in a variance matrix of size *10 x 4*, which can be used for calculations with *y_variance*.